# Do I remove Grub bootloader when shifting to an older version?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

Recently I had installed the newer version of Ubuntu 20.04 along side my Windows. However, soon realised that the software I wish to use on it are far more stable in the older version (Ubu-16.04).
Now, I followed the steps to remove the Ubuntu in order to put in the 16.04 version.
Now my question is:
Do I have to remove the grub bootloader of 20.04 for the older version to install its own ?

Comment: The `grub` software is located in /boot/grub, the MBR (first sector of a drive) is mostly just a pointer that allows the code to be found and run.  When you install another version of Ubuntu, it'll replace the MBR itself, and it's that MBR code which controls which `grub` is run (ie. which partition has the /boot/grub/ code that is used).  It doesn't need to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to remove the newer `grub` code.

The `grub` software is located in /boot/grub, the MBR (first sector of a drive) is mostly just a pointer that allows the code to be found and run.

When you install another version of Ubuntu, it'll replace the MBR itself, and it's that MBR code which controls which `grub` is run (ie. which partition has the /boot/grub/ code that is used).  It doesn't need to be removed

My system is dual boot; having two releases of Ubuntu (*groovy* and 18.04), both have `grub` installed, but only one is actually used - the one that I used to write the MBR

Comment: Thanks a lot mate ! How do you guys know this stuff ?! Thanks a lot.

Comment: fyi:  on both my systems, normal upgrades update the grub menus (ie. run `update-grub`) on both my systems (*groovy* is the code name for 20.10, it becomes 20.10 on release), however as only my *groovy* has it's pointer in the MBR (ie. it was on *groovy* where `grub-install` was run, or last run anyway) it's the grub I'll see when I boot.  On some other boxes (boxes with multiple disk drives [*note: drives, not partitions*]) changes in BIOS also impact it (as MBR is the first sector of a drive, BIOS controls which drive is first)